# Differential equation by exact equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve this problem:
$$y (1+ xy) dx - x dy =0$$
using an exact equation method, i.e., $M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = F.$

I got,
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = 1+2xy,$$
$$ \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}= -1.$$

The equation is

Clearly it is not exact. I tried making it exact using $\mu(x)$, $\mu(y)$ but to no avail.

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

$$y (1+ xy) dx - x dy =0\tag1$$which is of the form $$M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0$$where $~M(x,y)=y (1+ xy)~$ and $~N(x,y)=- x~$.

Here $$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = 1+2xy \qquad \text{and}\qquad \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}= -1$$
Now$$-\dfrac{1}{M}\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\right)=-\dfrac{1}{y (1+ xy)}\left(1+2xy+1\right)=-\dfrac{2}{y}=\phi(y)$$
Hence the integrating function (I.F.) is $$\text{I.F.}~=~e^{\int \phi(y)~dy}=\frac{1}{y^2}$$ 
Multiplying both side of $(1)$ by I.F. we have 
$$\dfrac{1}{y}(1+ xy) dx - \dfrac{x}{y^2} dy =0$$
$$\implies \frac {ydx-xdy}{y^2}+xdx=0$$
$$\implies d\left (\frac {x}{y} \right)+\dfrac 12~d(x^2)=0$$
Integrating we have $$\frac {x}{y} +\dfrac 12~x^2=C$$where $~C~$ is integrating constant.

---

---

**Rule:** If $~-\frac{1}{M}\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\right)~$i.e., $~\frac{1}{M}\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right)~$ is a function of $~y~$ alone, say $~\phi(y)~$, then $~e^{\int \phi(y)~dy}~$ is an integrating factor of $~M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0~$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ydx-xdy+xy^2dx=0$$
Rewrite the differential equation as:
$$\frac {ydx-xdy}{y^2}+xdx=0$$
It's exact:
$$2 d\left (\frac {x}{y} \right)+dx^2=0$$
After integration, it gives:
$$2 \left (\frac {x}{y} \right)+x^2=C$$

Comment: How do you know that the division factor is y^2? Is there any formula or is that observational? And why doesn't using my method yield integration factor?

Comment: Try to differentiate $(x/y)$ and see what you get at the denominator @user68153